# Python Pandas DataFrame new column based on conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling a but with the following Python Pandas Dataframe and adding a new column based on the values across columns .

The DataFrame looks as follows:

Before

```
   A  B
0  1  0
1  0  0
2 -1  0
3  0  1
4  1  0
5  0  0
6  0  1
7  0  0
```

The thing that I'm trying to accomplish is, iterate rows both of column A and B. When column A has a row with value of 1 it should check the next rows(A and B) for column B value of 1. But when Column A during iteration hits a row with -1 it should "reset" the search and continue looking for a new column A with value 1 on the remaining rows.

When both column A and B have a 1 without A hitting -1, column C should be created and set the value of the row to 1.

After

```
   A  B  C
0  1  0  0
1  0  0  0
2 -1  0  0
3  0  1  0
4  1  0  0
5  0  0  0
6  0  1  1 <---- Both A and B have a 1 without A hitting a -1
7  0  0  0
```

Tried to use

```
df['c'] = (df['a'].map(lambda x: 0 if (x <= 0) else 1) )
```

And

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
(Not the best i know)
```

But cannot seem to get the needed result

Comment: What if both `A` and `B` are `1` in the same row? What will the output in that case?

Comment: Also why is index 4 C not 1? B hits one in index 3 and A hits 1 in index 4. "Both A and B have hit 1 without A hitting negative 1" does A have to hit 1 first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution (you'll have to check the performance if your dataframe is very big):

first you have to get the index for your different relevant values

```
a_neg, a_pos, b_pos = df.index[df['A'] == -1].to_list(), df.index[df['A'] == 1].to_list(), df.index[df['B'] == 1].to_list()
```

then you loop over the values checking for the conditions that you described appending the true values to a list with the index for the `C` column:

```
c_index = []
for a_p in a_pos:
    for a_n in a_neg:
        for b_p in b_pos:
            if (b_p >= a_p and b_p < a_n):  # Assuming if A=1 and B=1 means C=1, if not the use b_p > a_p
                c_index.append(b_p)
            if b_p >= a_pos[-1] and b_p > a_neg[-1] and b_p not in c_index:  # Assuming if A=1 and B=1 means C=1, if not the use b_p > a_p
                c_index.append(b_p)
```

and then you fill the `C` column with `0` and assign `1` to the index you found in the column `C`:

```
df['C'] = 0
df.loc[c_index, 'C'] = 1
```

The whole code:

```
txt = '''   A  B
0  1  0
1  0  0
2 -1  0
3  0  1
4  1  0
5  0  0
6  0  1
7  0  0
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), header=0, skipinitialspace=True, sep=r'\s+', index_col=0)

a_neg, a_pos, b_pos = df.index[df['A'] == -1].to_list(), df.index[df['A'] == 1].to_list(), df.index[df['B'] == 1].to_list()
c_index = []

for a_p in a_pos:
    for a_n in a_neg:
        for b_p in b_pos:
            if (b_p >= a_p and b_p < a_n):
                c_index.append(b_p)
            if b_p >= a_pos[-1] and b_p > a_neg[-1] and b_p not in c_index:
                c_index.append(b_p)

df['C'] = 0
df.loc[c_index, 'C'] = 1
```

Output:

```
>>> print(df)

   A  B  C
0  1  0  0
1  0  0  0
2 -1  0  0
3  0  1  0
4  1  0  0
5  0  0  0
6  0  1  1
7  0  0  0
```

Comment: Yes this works! Many thanks.
The DataFrame isn't that big so that should not be an issue.